# How to "find all xml files in multiple directories (textfile) and delete"

Tags: linux, bash, find

I have a text file containing the full path to about 1000 directories. Each on a separate line.  I would like to delete all .xml files contained in these folders. I can obtain this one at a time using:

```
find /mnt/local/hhd1/output/data/2010-aug-ph1/ -name "*.xml" -type f -delete
```

but obviously will take a long time to do by hand. How do I get find to read each line and perform the delete from a text file?

Comment: Why do you need `find`, if you want to read from a text file and delete files ?

Comment: are you able to install any command-line tools?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a loop to read the directory names from your file and issue a `find ... -delete` on each of them:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read -r dir; do
  find "$dir" -name "*.xml" -type f -delete
done < file
```

Comment: Seems to be injecting a \r fro some reason. vi looks clean. No white space.
    find: ‘/mnt/local/pcps3/output/test/test/2010_sep_nov/7.1.4582.5/2016-07-15-14-12-18-ahill\r’: No such file or directory

Comment: Looks like `\r` is a part of your file that contains the list of directories, not the code above.  Use `:set list` in vi to see the special characters.

Comment: Yup. CTRL+M junk. Ran dos2unix on the file and its working now. Thanks a bunch!